# Converting date to seconds with strtotime

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Given that code:

```
$date = '2014-05-22';

$number = strtotime($date);
$number2 = "143134652600";

echo $number;
echo $number2;
echo date('Y-m-d', $number);
echo date('Y-m-d', $number2);
```

Output:

```
1400709600
143134652600
2014-05-22
2014-05-22
```

Why `$number` is not equal to `$number2`?

and how to convert a Y-m-d '2014-05-22' to the same format as `$number2` '143134652600'?

Comment: Your `$number2` looks bad to me. It's too long to be a timestamp with just seconds so it would have to have milliseconds included and that would cause it to be `Mon, 15 Jul 1974...`. Where has `$number2` come from?

Answer (score 0):

The output I get from that is:

```
1400731200
143134652600
2014-05-22 00:00:00
6505-10-03 20:43:20
```

I'm not sure how you get 2014-05-22 for both.